# ASP.Net Core WebAPI Entity Framework - Execute Sql Command on Startup

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

In my ASP.Net Core WebAPI I would like to set sql's SESSION_CONTEXT on startup to deposit the userId of the logged in user. I use row level security on MS SQL Server 2016 to limit data dependent on the userId in the SESSION_CONTEXT.

I am having problems executing a sql command on startup or rather on StateChange of my DbContext. I don't know how to add my code to StateChange-Event. Maybe there is also a better way to do this.

I am working with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0. I already tried this example: https://www.carlrippon.com/creating-a-multi-tenant-asp-net-core-web-api-with-sql-server-rls/

I failed because the example is made for EF 1 and doesn't work with version 2, i get the following error on start:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'DataContext' from root provider.

I have one more problem with getting the connection on DbContext "OnConfiguring". The connectionstring is located in the appsettings.json file and I use it on startup. Isn't it possible to get the connectionstring from DbContext OnConfiguring? The code on startup (UseSqlServer()) fires before OnConfiguring so the connectionstring must be somewhere...

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString = "<your connection string>";
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}

private void Connection_StateChange(object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"exec sp_set_session_context @key=N'TenantId', @value=@TenantId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TenantId", tenantId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<WfsDbContext>(options =>
{
 options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?